# Problemas com cache no Laravel 5.4

Tags: php-7, cache, laravel-5.4

Olá, estou com problemas aparentemente de cache no Laravel 5.4.
Quando dou um **UPDATE** em um formulário, direciono o usuário para a listagem dos registros.
Quando retorno para o formulário de edição do mesmo, os dados antigos (antes de realizar a alteração) ainda aparecem.
Apenas quando atualizo a página **F5** os dados corretos aparecem.
Para critério de eliminação, fiz um teste direto pelo controller (sem view) e o problema continua.
Já realizei procedimentos como:
***php artisan clear-compiled***
***php artisan cache:clear***
***php artisan config:clear***
***composer dump-autoload -o***

Forcei a exclusão de cache no construct do controller **Cache::flush();**
Mas o problema ainda continua!

Minha aplicação está rodando em uma VM da DigitalOcean (CENTOS - NGINX - PHP7)

Já passaram por isso? Obrigado!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problema resolvido!!**
O pacote http estava com um parâmetro dizendo para browser manter aquele conteúdo em cache por X tempo. 
Ou seja, por mais que eu tentasse mexer nos arquivos de cache do Laravel, nada surtia efeito.

**Solução:**
No arquivo de virtual host do **NGINX** na linha **expires** alterei o parâmetro de *max* para *off*.

Ficando assim:  ***expires off;***

No meu caso o arquivo estava localizado em: ***/etc/nginx/conf.d***
Para mais informações, segue a documentação do **NGINX**:
http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_headers_module.html#expires

```
Sintaxe:    expires [modified] time;
expires epoch | max | off;
Padrão: 
Expira;
Contexto:   http, server, location,if in location
```